# iOS Multipeer connectivity is limiting number of peers to 6 when using Bluetooth only, anyway to get around it?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, multipeer-connectivity

My multi-session multipeer implementation on iOS 9.3 works fine with 10+ devices when Wifi is available.

However, if the devices are limited to Bluetooth only, a maximum of 6 peers (i.e. 6+1 total number of devices) were observed. No matter how many sessions are involved, the total number of peers remained at a maximum of 6.

A new peer will be found and connected accordingly, but one of the connected peer will then be dropped and become NotConnected right after that.

Any insight of getting around this bluetooth only limitation ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can create multiple sessions to overcome this limitations

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a max allowed of simultaneous BLE connections on iOS, somewhere in the ranges of 6-8 (not official).

I would question why would you need to keep an opened connection all the time?

Peer to Peer implementations on mobile devices are very difficult, if your app is not a pure networking solution, i would recommend not to try and build the p2p yourself. There are several frameworks that can do that (and also iOS <-> Android) for you such as:
http://p2pkit.io or google nearby.

Disclaimer: i work for Uepaa developing p2pkit for iOS and Android.